# Transaction mismatch. Previous count = 1, current count = 0 , Entity Framework only

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have 3 SQL Objects:

1. Table `Employee` with three fields (id, name, salary)

   [image: 1]
2. Procedure `Insert_employee` [to insert in employee table]
3. Trigger [to make validation for table]

My problem: if call `Insert_employee` by Entity Framework,

> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.

```sql
ALTER PROC [dbo].[Insert_Employees]
(
  @id AS INT,
  @name AS NVARCHAR(max),
  @salary AS  NUMERIC(18,3)
)
AS 
BEGIN
  DECLARE @error AS NVARCHAR(max)

  BEGIN TRANSACTION

  INSERT INTO employee(Id, Name,Salary)
  SELECT @id, @name , @salary

  SELECT @error = @@ERROR

  IF @error = 0 COMMIT ELSE ROLLBACK
END

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[INS_employee] ON [dbo].[Employee] 
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE inserted.name = '')
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR('name is empty',16,1);
  END   
  ELSE                
    INSERT INTO employee(id, Name, Salary)
    SELECT id, Name, Salary FROM inserted
END
```

Comment: Why do you commit a transaction in `Insert_Employees` that you didn't start?

Comment: As an aside its recommended to use `throw` instead of `raiserror`.

Comment: Is the error only happening when you insert a blank name? And can you reproduce it in SSMS?

Comment: @GSerg , you means I do commit , rollback in trigger ?